# Shell Script: Search multiple string in a text file and display the line that contains the string

Tags: shell, unix, search

I am very new to the shell scripting world. I have done some research on this but seems not working so far.

What I am trying to do is I have two txt files. I want to search all the strings from file A in File B, and display all the lines from file B that has the strings in it.

So far, I only have this(please don't laugh)...

```
#!bin/sh
for LINE in 'cat $1'
do
grep '$LINE' $2
done
```

I guess I am trying to make it dynamic, so I can execute something like this

```
./script.ksh fileA.txt fileB.txt
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated and thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried `grep "$LINE" $2` instead of `grep '$LINE' $2` ?

Comment: I just did and it didn't come up with the results as I expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close to your goal, but there are some minor errors in your code.

This should work:

```
#!/bin/sh
for LINE in `cat $1`
do
    grep "$LINE" $2
done
```

Here's an example:

**fileA.txt:**

> ```
> Hi
> Hello
> Hairy
> Harry
> Hates
> His
> Home
> ```

**fileB.txt:**

> ```
> James Bond likes Harry
> Sylvia is cool
> Fiona is mad
> Hello there
> Hairy toenails
> ```

**Output:**

> ```
> Hello there
> Hairy toenails
> James Bond likes Harry
> ```

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for the quick reply. I just tried and the result is that I can't find anything. I created a file which contains a series of strings, and cut a portion of it into another file. The results is it didn't display anything.....

Comment: The order of the files you put in is of importance. The file containing strings to search for should be first, while the file being search should be last. Hope this helps! I added an example for reference.

Comment: Hello, I did create a file named try.sh, and created two files like yours. and then I ran the command like this:    ./try.sh fileA.txt fileB.txt     and it didn't show up the results like yours....

Comment: Make sure you change your **'** with **`** where you cat the file.

Answer (score 3):

No need for scripting:

```
grep -f $1 $2
```

Answer (score 0):

mate, your first line contains **two errors**, it should be this way:

```
#!  /bin/sh
```

I put some extra space so that you see the difference, this may be the cause for your script not working.

No big deal, typos happen and Bash can be very a real PIA with regards to white spaces.

BTW, what about good old diff ?

```
diff file1 file2
```

man 1 diff

;)